# Capturing an Objective-C object weakly within C block without declaring an explicit __weak or __block variable

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, weak-references

I am capturing a method-scoped object in a C block and I want to avoid retain cycles. Here is my code: (`balloon` is a custom view created within my current method)

```
balloon.onAddedToViewHierarchy = ^{
        CGRect globalRect = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow convertRect:self.frame fromView:self.superview];
        CGRect targetFrame = CGRectMake(20, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH - 40, 60);
        targetFrame.origin.y = below ? globalRect.origin.y + globalRect.size.height + 10 : globalRect.origin.y - 10 - 60/*height*/;
        balloon.frame = globalRect;//targetFrame;
    };
```

at the last line (`balloon.frame = globalRect;`) I am told that capturing `balloon` in block will lead to a retain cycle. I know about ARC, ownerships, retain counts etc and I know the reason. I am just looking for a way to implicitly get rid of retaining `balloon` (it's already guaranteed to be retained by being referenced from other places) and using a `__weak` pointer, or `__block` if appropriate. I know I can do this:

```
__weak UIView *weakBalloon = balloon;
balloon.onAddedToViewHierarchy = ^{
        CGRect globalRect = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow convertRect:self.frame fromView:self.superview];
        CGRect targetFrame = CGRectMake(20, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH - 40, 60);
        targetFrame.origin.y = below ? globalRect.origin.y + globalRect.size.height + 10 : globalRect.origin.y - 10 - 60/*height*/;
        weakBalloon.frame = globalRect;//targetFrame;
    };
```

But actually I'm exploring ways to implement the same behavior without explicitly creating a new pointer. I am looking for something like this: (it won't compile, just a demo)

```
balloon.onAddedToViewHierarchy = ^{
        CGRect globalRect = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow convertRect:self.frame fromView:self.superview];
        CGRect targetFrame = CGRectMake(20, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH - 40, 60);
        targetFrame.origin.y = below ? globalRect.origin.y + globalRect.size.height + 10 : globalRect.origin.y - 10 - 60/*height*/;
        ((__weak UIView*)balloon).frame = globalRect;//targetFrame;
    };
```

Is something similar possible? I know there's nothing wrong with declaring a `__weak` variable, it will just work perfectly. I'm just curious that if such an implicit behavior is possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the `@weakify` and `@strongify` macros, included in [Reactive Cocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) or the [Extended Objective-C Library](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc).

For demonstration of this, see the *Avoiding Retain Cycles* discussion in Ray Wenderlich's 
[part 2 of 2 discussion about Reactive Cocoa](http://www.raywenderlich.com/62796/reactivecocoa-tutorial-pt2).

That article provides the following example:

```
__weak RWSearchFormViewController *bself = self; // Capture the weak reference

[[self.searchText.rac_textSignal map:^id(NSString *text) {
    return [self isValidSearchText:text] ? [UIColor whiteColor] : [UIColor yellowColor];
  }]
  subscribeNext:^(UIColor *color) {
    bself.searchText.backgroundColor = color;
  }];
```

Which they go on to suggest could be replaced with:

```
@weakify(self)
[[self.searchText.rac_textSignal map:^id(NSString *text) {
    return [self isValidSearchText:text] ? [UIColor whiteColor] : [UIColor yellowColor];
  }]
  subscribeNext:^(UIColor *color) {
    @strongify(self)
    self.searchText.backgroundColor = color;
  }];
```